# Get products stock quantity in my cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get `stock quantity` for all products in my cart `Magento 2` and check if they are in stock or out of stock ?

Comment: You want Quantity for   those products which are in cart now?

Comment: Yes I need the stock quantity for each product in cart, not cart quantity.

Comment: please try this to getQty of the Product... $item->getProduct()->getQty();

Comment: It is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Extend block with your custom block using di.xml
2. Load `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface` object in your construct function using dependency injection method.
3. Get current your store Id. It is possible that cart block already method for that.
4. Try to use `$stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $storeId)->getQty();`

**Update:**
- I believe you can get store id from item itself `$item->getStoreId()`
- Keep in mind to use product id not item id (item id is product id on the quote)
It would be something like this : $item->getProduct()->getId();